# Convert smallint to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to convert a `smallint` to a `time` format.

I am using SQL Server 2005 which doesn't support the `time` datatype.

I am storing the time as 1400 which is a `smallint`. When retrieving I want it to be converted to a time format. Such as `14:00`

Any ideas or guidance on the matter. If there is an easier way to do it or if the way I am trying is possible?

Comment: Are you wanting this converted to a varchar `14:00`?  How are you wanting this to be converted?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "time format"?   Since you can't return the `time` datatype in SQL 2005, do you want a varchar?   a datetime?

Comment: either tbh, finding out the ways possibe before making a decision @TabAlleman

Comment: @TabAlleman valuable stackoverflow help. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a result as `varchar` by using this:

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(10), yourTime / 100), 2) + ':' +  
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(10), yourTime % 100), 2) As timeString
FROM
    yourTable
```

You can also have a result in `DATETIME` format like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), yourTime / 100)+ ':' + CONVERT(varchar(10), yourTime % 100))
FROM
    yourTable
```

---

In SQL Server 2012+ you can have a result in time format:

```
SELECT 
    TIMEFROMPARTS(yourTime / 100, yourTime % 100, 0, 0, 0) As timeFormat
FROM 
    yourTable
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentions in his question he's using SQL Server 2005, which does not support the `TIME` datatype.

Comment: Not my dv but `TIMEFROMPARTS` isn't available in 2005.