# teradata: convert smallint to time

Tags: sql, teradata

Alright, I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439212/convert-smallint-to-time) and tried what was suggested but this did not seem to work for me. Appreciate the help! Thanks!

Here are datatypes for individual columns:

column_names: `col_dt [DATE]col_tm [SMALLINT]`

data samples:

`col_dt: 2017-08-10`
`col_tm: 1,630`

Here is my code snippet. I'm trying to combine both the columns into one using the following code:

`(trim(col_dt) || ' ' ||`
`right('0' + convert(varchar(10), col_tm/100),2) + ':' +`
`right('0' + convert(varchar(10),col_tm%100),2)) as col_dtmstp,`

Comment: Syntax error : expected something between "||" and the 'right' keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `col_dt` to a timestamp, which results in midnight and then double cast `col_tm` to a tring first and then to an `interval`:

```
Cast(col_dt AS TIMESTAMP(0)) 
+ Cast(Trim(col_tm (Format '99:99')) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE)
```

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth. The solution you provided worked. However, I had incorrectly mentioned in the question (my apologies) that the col_date format has 'YYYY-MM-DD'; instead it is in 'dd/mm/yyyy'. All my other columns are in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format and I would prefer col_date to show in same way.

Comment: @k.learn: When `col_dt` is a `date` there's no need to do anything, as the default format for a timestamp is already `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'

Answer (score 0):

In the post you mentioned, they are using `right` function which is not built-in function in teradata sql. you can use `CAST` function instead.

Below is the query which will generate your desired result in datatype `TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT Cast(Trim('2017-08-10' 
          || ' ' 
          ||Trim(Cast(1630 / 100 AS CHAR(10))) 
          || ':' 
          || Trim(Cast(1630 MOD 100 AS CHAR(10))) 
          || ':00') AS TIMESTAMP(0) Format 'yyyy-mm-ddBhh:mi:ss');
```

It is successfully tested both with Teradata SQL Assistant and bteq. You can confirm its datatype using `type[expression]` function.