# Calculate number of hours inside the query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores hours when a business is open.

```
t1
----------------------
id  |  open  |  closed
```

The two columns that store hours are type `smallint` and the value looks something like this:

> **800** for 8:00 AM
> **2200** for 10:00 PM
>
> **0** for midnight

I need to calculate the number of hours the business stays open. For example:

```
Open: 1000
Closed: 2200
Hours: 12
```

Can at least a part of this be done inside a query? Or shall I output the data and then do all the computations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439212/convert-smallint-to-time, cast then use timediff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing it as a `smallint` is problematic.

You can substract 2200 - 1000 = 1200, then divide by 1000 to get number of hours, but you'll get in trouble when having 2200 - 1030 = 1130. 
It's doable, but why to make your life difficult?

You can keep the data as `time` field and just use `timediff` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

```
SELECT id, open, closed, TIMEDIFF(closed, open) AS hours FROM ...
```

Comment: OK, this makes a lot of sense. Can I just change the column type to time or do i need to do some sort of conversion?

Comment: definitelly a convestion, unfortunatelly I don't have a mysql server installed. But you can divide (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) by 100 (1230 DIV 100 = 12) to get number of hours, and use module operation to get number of minutes (1230 % 100 = 30), then just `CONCAT` to make a time string.

Comment: OK, I can try and re-insert data again after I change the type for hours, however, type TIME expects it in the following format: HH:MM:SS and I have values like 830... Do I need to pad the values to have 6 digits?

Comment: Your `smallint` solution doesn't have place for seconds, so just glue `:00` at the end.

Comment: What about midnight, which is 0? Just leave it?

Comment: Why not replace it with `00:00:00`?